# How to display info from database into controls inside a gridview, listview, datalist itemtemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I bind data or info from a database table to the labels inside a datalist, listview or gridview ITEMTEMPLATE?

I have a table `Product_table(Pro_id,pro_imagepath)`.

I want to have a datalist or listview in which the itemtemplate contains an image control and a label. I would like to bind the pro_imagepath to the image control inside the itemtemplate, and the pro_id to the label inside the itemtemplate.

Comment: this is webforms 101, there are plenty of examples online, just search for `asp.net item template example`

Comment: Which technology do you use for data access: LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities or maybe raw ADO.NET DataReader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your list view has already been databound you should just be able to use `<%#Eval("pro_imagepath")%>` and `<%#Eval("Pro_id")%>` respectively.

To use those inside of a control you will need to do something like this.

```
<asp:Image id="img1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("pro_imagepath")%>' />
```

Be sure that the properties of the control you want to bind are using single quotes instead of double quotes when putting an EVAL() in them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:label id="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Pro_id")%>' />
 <asp:image id="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("pro_imagepath")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

You just need to bind your data to your widget.

Comment: @JeffTurner I edited Saswat's question, I didn't ask the question. :)

Comment: I realized that after looking a bit closer :). Still relatively new to actually participating here!

Comment: @JeffTurner No worries. BTW, I just formatted your answer a little bit better.